# How to apply a formula to only visible cells macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet where I filter from row 1 column W and then apply a formula to the next visible cell. The next visible cell varies each week. It could be 1160 one week then 1165 the next, etc.

How can I write macro code that will pick up on the next visible cell no matter what row it is. It could be something simple that says "start on E1 and drop down to the next visible cell in column E" because then I don't mind using active cell formula entry.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you.

Here's what I have:

```
 With Sheets("Data").Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)("W1")
      .Value = "My Formula"
 End With
```

Comment: `Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` should be helpful.

Comment: How would I tell the program to go to the next visible cell though. I've used (xlCellTypeVisible) a lot in the past for copying and deleting rows after filtering. but I don't know the code to put with that to make the cursor go there.

Comment: You don't need to "make the cursor go there" to insert a formula though. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: Did what I add in my initial post bring me closer? I used some of the info from your link but I have minimal coding knowledge so I didn't fully understand much of it. How do I get that code to look at Col W?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly:

```
With Sheets("Data").Range("W:W").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(2)
    .Formula = "My Formula"
End With
```

Comment: I dropped the .Cells(2) off the end and it seems to do the trick for me. Thank you I can work with this.